# Cannot access JBoss using localhost in my machine but working fine with loopback IP and HostName even in Remote Machine

Tags: jboss7.x

I am using JBoss Server with Maven plugin and I cannot access the JBoss Application using localhost:8080. But using loopback ip(127.0.0.1) or HostName is working fine. I can even access it in other machines in my network using hostname. But using localhost in my machine is not working.
I am using JBoss-7.1.1 on a windows7 machine.

Comment: check your .host file. you can enter mapping of localhost and then check.

Comment: where can I find this .host file?

Comment: in Windows
Windows\System32\drivers\etc

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a network problem and not a JBoss issue.

Make sure that the loopback IP (127.0.0.1) is correctly set in your host file.

Also check the configured interfaces of JBoss.

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Interfaces+and+ports

Comment: The loopback is correctly set. I can run Tomcat successfully with localhost using another portnumber. Facing the issue only with JBoss.

Comment: In that case make sure that JBoss is correctly bound to the interface, under the interfaces section in your XML configuration file.

Comment: All the addresses in the <interface> in the standalone.xml are bound to 0.0.0.0.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 means bind to all IPs assigned to the computer, so this leads more towards a problem of your network configuration. Try setting this to 127.0.0.1 and see if localhost works. Also please include this <interfaces> section in your question so we can help further, and post the result of "tracert localhost".